# How can I kill a process based on the version number of its .EXE file?

Tags: delphi, process

I want to find a process that belongs to a .EXE file with a specific file version number, and kill it.  How can I do that?

I am working with Delphi, but any general help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

You can't "kill the file by only looking inside the version." You can kill a process if you have a handle to it. There are two common ways to get a process handle:

1. Use the handle you got when you started the process with [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx).
2. Get a handle to an already-running process with `OpenProcess`.

I'll assume you haven't started the process yourself, so you'll need to use [`OpenProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320.aspx).

Then the issue turns to choosing which process to try to open. `OpenProcess` requires a process ID, and there are a few ways to get one of those, depending on what other information you already have about the process.

- If you have a window handle that belongs to the process, then use [`GetWindowThreadProcessID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522.aspx).
- If you know the name of the process EXE file, then use [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682489.aspx) and then [`Process32First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684834.aspx) and [`Process32Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684836.aspx) to inspect each process until you find one that matches.
- If you only know the name of the window, then use [`FindWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499.aspx) or [`EnumWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497.aspx) to get a window handle, and then use the first method.

If you are concerned about the version number of the EXE file, then consider using the second method, but before you choose the process, open the EXE file and check the contents. That's a sufficiently different task from killing a process that if you have trouble with it, you should ask about it in a separate question.

Once you have the handle to the process you're interested in, you can kill it with [`TerminateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714.aspx). Please heed the warnings in the documentation for that function; it's not a clean process shutdown by any stretch.

Finally, be careful that you observe the difference between window handles and process handles. They are not interchangeable. Use the `HWnd` type when you want to hold a window handle; `THandle` for process handles.

Answer (score 0):

try and use the taskkill command, it has more control over what to filter by.

Beyond that your question is very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill a task by process name like this:

```
taskkill /im MyProcess.exe /f
```

But it sounds like you want to kill it based on the file version number.  Is that correct?

Comment: I don't know the answer (yet) but I've modified your question in a way that I hope is clearer.  If you disagree, feel free to roll it back.